# Could somehow the fundamental laws and symmetries of physics change or be broken?

Tags: energy, symmetry, universe, laws-of-physics

There are some theoretical processes (like vacuum decay in quantum field theory) that could change the physical constants of the universe. Similarly, in inflation theory, various models predict that multiple regions that would stop inflating would become "bubble universes" perhaps with different constants of nature. Something similar happens with string theory landscape of vacua...

But could there be any process that would fundamentally rewrite every fundamental law that we know? Any process that would break every symmetry and law of physics that we can think of and just absolute randomness and chaos would govern? Perhaps, and this is just a gedankenexperiment, a situation where an infinite amount of energy exist or where there is an infinite amount of energy density could do it?

Comment: *Broken symmetry*/*spontaneous symmetry breaking* has very specific meaning in physics. I could suggest taking a look at Anderson's [More is different: broken symmetry and the nature of hierarchical structure of science](https://www.tkm.kit.edu/downloads/TKM1_2011_more_is_different_PWA.pdf)

Comment: Randomness can be described by probability amplitudes, chaos - by bifurcators, attractors, etc. If in your imaginary universe, there will be intelligent creatures,- for sure they will try to chop and classify the chaotic world rules as they see it, by the very fact of their existence. If they will not be there, well - we don't know what we don't know. As for now, physical laws are not expiring, but superseded by more general and advanced theories, which describe nature better at greater resolution.

Comment: @RogerVadim but as far as I understand it (and correct me if I am wrong), there are multiple theories which propose some kind of (spontaneous) symmetry breaking but they do not suppose that the most fundamental laws would changed or be replaced by others completely different (like cosmological inflation, which despite assuming some symmetry breaking, the hypothetical universes that it proposes would all have the same underlying fundamental laws)

Answer (score 1):

Are you suggesting a new meta-law of physics, according to which the laws of physics stop or change when a particular thing happens?

One may speculate about this and similar things (e.g. as Celia Green put it, whether "everything might stop existing at any moment or start existing according to different laws"). Is there a reason why the laws are whatever they are? What is a law of physics, and why and how is it enforced?

One thing such questions have in common, is that they are at a philosophical level above the usual task of fundamental physics, which is just to discover the facts about the physical world - i.e., to find out what the laws are, and not what they could be. From this perspective, one may feel free to only care about possibilities for which there is some evidence. Unless you have evidence, you're doing metaphysics I guess - asking what's logically possible, rather than asking what's actual.

Physics and metaphysics are not completely independent; in theory something might be discovered empirically, because someone conceived it as a logical possibility and decided to look for it. John Wheeler was fascinated by the fact that general relativity predicts singularities but doesn't predict what they lead to, and mused about whether this is a glimpse of something beyond physical law as ordinarily conceived. However, there have been decades of work since then, on the quantum mechanics of black holes, and there is no longer any special reason to suppose that black holes represent a breakdown of physical law per se, they're just a region where new aspects of physical law are at work. So I would say the only known quasi-empirical motivation for your scenario, has ended long ago.

Answer (score 1):

Physics isn't like Euclidean geometry, with its unchanging postulates and theorems. The "laws of physics" are always changing. They are, in the end, stories we tell about the phenomena we observe. We constantly refine them and extend them, changing them to accommodate newly observed phenomena. They are the most effective stories we have, but in the end they are just stories.

You seem to want laws that are more than human stories. You can't have them. There is, ultimately, no way to test whether a particular "law" will apply to all phenomena.